# make the output to odd and even?

Tags: php

the original code is as the following:

```
  <?php

    foreach($values as $value){

        $downlink=node_load($value);

    echo '<li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>.$downlink->title.'</li>';
    }

?>
```

i want to make the output to

```
 <li class="odd">...</li>
<li class="even">...</li>
.....
```

this is my ways. but it is not work.

```
$i=0;
foreach($values as $value){

            $downlink=node_load($value);
          if($i%2==0){
echo '<li class="even"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>.$downlink->title.'</li>';}
else{
        echo '<li class="odd"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>.$downlink->title.'</li>';
}
$i++;
        }
```

Comment: Why doesnt it work? Whats the error you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of doing is perfect but it has a small glitch that might be causing it not to work as intended. It seems you are missing a ' (single-quote) after the starting <li> tag after "/>" in both your statements.

This is how it should look (notice the bold single-quote):

echo '<li class="even"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>**'** . $downlink->title . '</li>'

Another thing though not related - it is not required to put an ending / (forward-slash) at the end of the starting <li> tag because it has it own ending tag </li>

Answer (score 8):

My own personal method for doing this server side is:

```
foreach ($foo as $bar) { 

  $class = ($class == "even") ? "odd" : "even";

  echo "<li class='".$class."'>blah blah</li>";

}
```

Comment: if the foreach loop does the first. which value will be assigned to the class. there is no value to compare with the class. how to output even or odd? thank you

Comment: Because prior to the first iteration of the loop, $class isn't equal to anything, it will be set to "odd" (because it doesn't currently equal "even").  You should probably pre-set it though, because trying to compare $class when it isn't set will probably generate a PHP notice to your screen or to your log, if you have that level of error reporting enabled.

Comment: when the second iteration of the loop,the $class  is also not  equal to anything.how output even? thank you.

Comment: On the second iteration, the value of $class in the example above would initially be "odd" (having been set to that in the first iteration) and it would be reset to "even" because its not already equal to "even".  On the third, being "even", it would get set to "odd", and so on....

Comment: Classy way to avoid any more code than necessary (though you may need to set $class = null; outside of the loop to code to strict.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve odd/even coloring with CSS alone:

```
li:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
li:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

[Browser support for nth-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild#compatibilitysection) selectors may vary though.

See http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd

Answer (score 1):

another note :

start from `$i=1;`

and its start from odd

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a quote:

```
$i=0;
foreach($values as $value){
        $downlink=node_load($value);
         if($i%2==0){
             echo '<li class="even"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>'.$downlink->title.'</li>';}
else{
        echo '<li class="odd"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>.$downlink->title.'</li>';
}
$i++;
        }
```

Comment: he's actually missing single quotes both near in `checked="checked"/>.$downlink->title`

Answer (score 0):

Modify like below:

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    foreach($values as $value){
    $downlink=node_load($value); ?>
    <li class="<?php echo ($i%2==0) ? 'even' :'odd'" ?>>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><?php echo $downlink->title;?></li>
    <?php 
          $i++;
    }//end of foreach
```

**Note:** why u put `checked=checked` for all checkbox?? your logic may b wrong here